# How to include opening_hours.js into a node.js script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to use [*opening_hours.js*](https://github.com/opening-hours/opening_hours.js) in a *node.js* shell script. The library and its dependency [*SunCalc*](https://github.com/mourner/suncalc) are available locally:

- js/suncalc.js
- js/opening_hours.js

I would like to use *opening_hours.js* in the script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// TODO: load libraries

var oh = new opening_hours('We 12:00-14:00');
```

Of interest might be the following excerpts from the javascript files:

from *opening_hours.js*:

```
// make the library accessible for the outside world {{{
if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    var moment, SunCalc, i18n;
    // For Node.js.
    SunCalc = root.SunCalc || require('suncalc');
    try { // as long as it is an optional dependency
        moment = root.moment || require('moment');
    } catch (error_pass) { error_pass }
    try { // as long as it is an optional dependency
        i18n = require('./locales/core');
    } catch (error_pass) { error_pass }
    module.exports = factory(SunCalc, moment, i18n, holiday_definitions, word_error_correction, lang);
} else {
    // For browsers.
    root.opening_hours = factory(root.SunCalc, root.moment, root.i18n, holiday_definitions, word_error_correction, lang);
}
//* }}} */
```

from *suncalc.js*:

```
// export as AMD module / Node module / browser variable
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) define(SunCalc);
else if (typeof module !== 'undefined') module.exports = SunCalc;
else window.SunCalc = SunCalc;
```

Comment: What's the issue with `require('./js/opening_hours')` ?

Comment: This raises: `Error: Cannot find module 'suncalc'`.

Comment: I see the problem, I'll add an answer

Comment: `require('./js/suncalc') require('./js/opening_hours')` raise the same error. They are available locally for other parts of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `opening_hours.js` is expecting SunCalc to be installed as an NPM module. You need to update the `require` statement in the code you posted to point to the local SunCalc file:

```
// make the library accessible for the outside world {{{
if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    var moment, SunCalc, i18n;
    // For Node.js.
    SunCalc = root.SunCalc || require('./suncalc'); // CHANGED
    try { // as long as it is an optional dependency
        moment = root.moment || require('moment');
    } catch (error_pass) { error_pass }
    try { // as long as it is an optional dependency
        i18n = require('./locales/core');
    } catch (error_pass) { error_pass }
    module.exports = factory(SunCalc, moment, i18n, holiday_definitions, word_error_correction, lang);
} else {
    // For browsers.
    root.opening_hours = factory(root.SunCalc, root.moment, root.i18n, holiday_definitions, word_error_correction, lang);
}
//* }}} */
```

Comment: With this the previous errors disappear. A new error occurs at my method call: `ReferenceError: opening_hours is not defined`. Besides: any way to solve this without changing the library - keep in mind it still has to function for the "Browser" part of the project.

Comment: Well you could install opening_hours as a npm module and negate the need to have it saved locally

Comment: Okay, thank you. **I will use the NPM modules for the script.** Is your change in the library a subject for being [included into the project](https://github.com/opening-hours/opening_hours.js/issues)?

Comment: The NPM module installs SunCalc as a dependency so that change should not be needed once you use the modules: https://github.com/opening-hours/opening_hours.js/blob/master/package.json#L50

Comment: I installed both libraries as NPM modules now. Then the change is no needed here.